# How can I make 'man' more gui friendly?

Tags: gedit, manpage

When I type `man bash` it shows the info in the terminal itself.

How do I tell "`man`" to open up the info in gedit instead? Is this possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use this function in .bashrc:

```
man () { yelp "man:$@"; }
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/190246/is-it-possible-to-open-man-help-file-in-gedit-with-a-command)

Comment: Thanks! This is better than gedit too (didn't know about yelp)

Comment: Or just use `yelp man:bash` of course, if you are on somebody else's desktop.

Comment: And if you need a manpage that's not in the default section, use something like `yelp "man:init(5)"` instead of `man 5 init` (this doen't work with the current version of *zengr*'s bash function).

Comment: That's very good.  Still, I'd also like a method to index or browse the man pages by topic or a table of content.  Is there anything like that out there that works on say just ubuntu or even just debian with X?

Answer (score 4):

Simply enter the following in the terminal:

```
man bash >/tmp/t;gedit /tmp/t
```

That will create a temporary file with the contents of the man page and open it with `gedit`.

Comment: An alternative command that avoids the creation of a temporary file, making use of Bash features: `gedit <(man bash)`

Comment: @Lekensteyn: *gedit* doesn't open a `<()` process substitution, nor does it open piped input. (tested in 2.30.3, and 3.4.1)

Comment: @Peter.O I just checked and you are true. It does not work for `kate` either. `nano` can open it as read-only though.

Comment: `man bash | gedit -` avoids the tmp file

Answer (score 3):

Better yet, have man format it in HTML and open it in firefox

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# open a man page in firefox

# loop through all parameters in order
for i
do
    # if the manpage was found, spawn it in a browser window
    man -f "$i" > /dev/null && coproc man --html=firefox "$i"
done
```

Comment: Excellent, I love it. +1 .. It is now a function in my `~/bashrc` ... `fman () { until [[ -z $1 ]] ;do man -f "$1" 2>/dev/null && coproc man --html=firefox "$1"; shift; done; }`

Comment: truly amazing. this way text overflows normally from a line to the next.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a shell: hit alt+f2 and enter `yelp man:bash`.
A command history is also available, and you can choose any manpage by replacing `man:bash` with the manpage you need.

Answer (score 1):

As well as opening the man page in `gedit` (like the other answers have demonstrated), you can also make a pdf of the man page (as first noted [in this article](http://www.unixmen.com/11-useful-commands-for-linuxunix-administrators/)) and then display it in `evince`. (You need `ps2pdf` and `evince` installed). The pdf file is created in your present working directory and is retained after `evince` is closed.

Simply modify the command below according to the man page that you want and change the file names or else the resulting pdf files will be overwritten. Here is an example for `dpkg`:

```
man -t dpkg | ps2pdf - dpkg.pdf && evince dpkg.pdf
```

However, it is probably much more useful to construct a function. You could add the following function to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` (assuming you have `evince` and `ps2pdf` installed; the latter is in the `ghostscript` package):

```
mikman() { man -t "$1" | ps2pdf - "$1".pdf && setsid evince "$1".pdf; }
```

After adding the function, you have to run `. .bashrc` (or `. .bash_aliases`) to source your configuration files, or restart the terminal for it to take effect.

Call the function with the name of any program that has a manpage, such as `mikman dpkg`, and it will carry out the commands and launch the manpage as a pdf. Launching the manpage as a pdf in your pdf reader gives you a very useful gui wherein search tools and the like can be utilised.

Comment: This is the best because it actually runs full  preprocessors typeseting things like eqn(1) equations (`man -t glFrustum`), pic(1) diagrams (`man -t soelim`), tbl(1) tables (`man -t nft`) etc! .  It's also possible to use TeX's dvi format instead of postscript, for even better results (especially for eqn formulas): `man -Tdvi glMultMatrix > t.dvi && dvipdfmx t.dvi && xdg-open t.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

On a case-by-case basis you can do:

`man mount > mount.txt`

The .txt file will be in your current directory.

`man mount > mount.txt && gedit mount.txt`

will open the file in gedit.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse man pages on-line http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ or install [dwww package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/dwww) and browse all documentation off-line (`http://localhost/dwww`). See description of [dwww package](http://packages.debian.org/stable/dwww) and/or read [man dwww](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/dwww.1.html) after installation.

You may be also interested in browsing package contents – install [dpkg-www package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/dpkg-www) and do the same: See description of [dpkg-www package](http://packages.debian.org/stable/dpkg-www) and/or read [man dpkg-www](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/dpkg-www.1.html) after installation. Start `dpkg-www` or browse `http://localhost/cgi-bin/dpkg`.

Answer (score -1):

This will create a temporary file with the manual page for bash in your home directory entitled "man" and open it with gedit. As soon as you close gedit the file will be erased too. Just replace bash with whatever man page you want to open.

```
man bash >> ~/man && gedit ~/man && rm ~/man
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The problem with this is that `gedit` detaches itself from the terminal with an exit code of `0`, so the `rm` step is executed immediately. This causes `~/man` to be deleted before *gedit* has even loaded it...