# How to change Manual pages default font?

Tags: command-line, manpage

When I type `man fork`, terminal output, but I dislike the default font , how to change into the other font?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/253705/graphical-user-interface-to-view-man-page

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Go from menu **Edit** > **Profiles**.
3. On the **Profile edit** window, click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button.
4. Finally, in the **General tab**, uncheck **Use the system fixed-width font**, and then select your desired font from the dropdown menu

Comment: This answer won't help change the font **only** for `man fork`