# How open "man node" or other informational command line's output in a text editor?

Tags: command-line, text-editor

I'm working with command line and sometime some informational - as manuals readMe and all - output are very large and hard to read in a one shot from the command's line. 
I wonder how open it directly on a text editor ?

I have tried `gedit man  node`  but it does'nt work. If any have some hint, would be gr

Comment: Possibly [How can I make 'man' more gui friendly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36020/how-can-i-make-man-more-gui-friendly) or [Graphical user interface to view man page?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253705/graphical-user-interface-to-view-man-page)

Answer (score 0):

`man command | col -b > file.txt` 
should do the trick.

this saves the manpage of command to file.txt, which you can open with a text editor like gedit.

But if you have an internet connection, I would suggest an online manpage resource like [Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/)